# Picker (any view) gets cutoff when trying to make a collapsible container

Tags: appcelerator

In appcelerator, there doesn't seem to be a control to make a collapsible "div", so I thought I would spin one up myself.

1.) Create a parent `View`(height 50), add a label (Displayed, meant to be clicked), and a picker (hidden) - and put the label & picker in the parent view.

2.) on click of label, animate the parent View to height: 150.

3.) show the picker.

However, the picker gets cutoff at height: 50 (the original size of the View). If I adjust the parent view to an original height of 70, the picker gets cutoff at 70. Is there an issue in the way I'm rendering my view - is there a better way?

```
options_label.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var animation = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
        animation.height = 150
        var animationHandler = function() {
           animation.removeEventListener('complete',animationHandler);
           picker.show()
        };
        animation.addEventListener('complete',animationHandler);
        category_option.animate(animation)

    })
```

[image]

Comment: Its very difficult to say what the problem is without knowing how the parent view and picker are laid out and added to the parent window. Can you provide more code?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered issues like this in appcelerator a number of times. The fixes usually involve switching around the order of events. Unfortunately, this is more or less a trial and error process, so here goes my best guesses:

1. Instead of creating the picker at initialisation, and then showing it on animation complete, only create and add the picker to the `category_option` view in the `animationHandler` function.
2. If the above doesn't appeal to you, try forcing the height of the picker to whatever looks right, by setting its height property. This should force it to schedule a relayout, hopefully making it realise that its parent view is now larger.

My best guess as to why this might be happening is that the `show()` method of the picker is not causing a relayout of the component. This would leave it thinking that it still in a 50 unit heigh view, and crop itself accordingly. I could be completely wrong about that, however, its just speculation.